# bootstrap tour in backbone.js single page application

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, single-page-application

I am not sure on how to use bootstrap-tour with backbone.js SPA.I created a view in which tour code is written and called by render method.When tour is started it is redirected to the path mentioned in the step but the message tip is not shown.Any links for bootstrap tour+backbone.js is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
define(["backbone","app"],
        function(Backbone,app){
    var TourView=Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){

        }, 
        render:function(){
            self=this;
            var url=self.url();
            var tour = new Tour({
                steps: [{
                  element: "#fname",
                  title: "Title of my step",
                  content: "Content of my step",
                  path: url+"#Search"
                }, {
                  element: "name",
                  title: "Title of my step",
                  content: "Content of my step",
                  path:url+"#tasks"
                }]
              });
            tour.init();
            tour.start();
        },
        url :function (){
            var gurl=app.context();
            return gurl;
        }
    });
    return TourView;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tour object contructor might not be available to this module. The modules that are available to/ required by this module are "Backbone and app". I hope the Tour object constructor is included in the bootstrap-tour.js, then this javascript file must be added as a dependency to this module.